# Python loop returning wrong value when multiplying digits in a string

Tags: python

This function is supposed to take a string of numbers(snum) and then the index it is supposed to start at (indx) and then starting at that (indx) and multiply the next (dig) amount of numbers and return the value. This is current funciton should return 72 but it is returning 41472. Thank you!

```
def product(dig, indx, snum):
    length = int(len(snum))
    int(indx)
    int(dig)
    total = int(snum[indx])

    for k in range((indx + 1), length):
        for i in range(0, dig):
            total = total * int(snum[k])

    else:
        return total


x = product(3, 5, '72890346')

print(x)
```

Comment: Why you need two loops here? If I understand you correctly, you should do: `for k in range(indx + 1, index + dig):`.

Comment: That was absolutely correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Following should do it :

```
def product(dig, indx, snum):
   mul = 1
   for s in snum[indx : indx+dig+1]:     #Note the `dig+1`
      mul *= int(s)                      #multiply the number

   return mul
```

Driver code :

```
x = product(3, 5, '72890346')
print(x)
#72
```

In your code, the logic has few problems. You do not need two loops. Here, we are using `slicing` operation to get characters between `indx` and `indx+dig`, and then converting the `string` we got to `int` and multiplying.